# Deploy war from S3 to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have 2 AWS machines, `1.dev (ec2) 2. prod (elastic beanstalk)`. I build and deploy on dev (machine1) after every commit which results into a war file (which will also be uploaded on an S3 bucket using s3cmd tool). Then I test the newly deployed war on dev machine, if it seems fine, then I download the war from dev(ec2) and then upload it to the prod machine (Elastic beanstalk).

Is there a way to make elastic beanstalk to take the war directly from the S3 bucket, rather than downloading it from ec2 and then uploading it to elastic beanstalk?

I tried creating new environment and then gave s3 bucket path for application version, but it din't work. (gave some error saying "this can only be done in VPC").

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have got the best answer in [this post](http://www.deplication.net/2013/11/java-war-deployment-options-on-aws.html) :

it requires 3 simple steps using AWS CLI:

1. Upload to S3 bucket: **aws s3 cp** /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT.war s3://elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-*xxxxxx*/**myROOT.war**
2. Create application version: **aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version** --application-name *your_app_name* --version-label *your_version_label* --source-bundle S3Bucket=elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-*xxxxxx*,S3Key=**myROOT.war**
3. Update your environment: **aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment** --environment-name *your_environment_name* --version-label *your_version_label*

I have created a [bash script](https://github.com/thekosmix/AWS-Deploy), which takes just 3 seconds for all the above steps. Do go through the link for more descriptive answer.

Comment: In AWS docco http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deployment.html

Answer (score 2):

If your s3 war file is in mybucket/test/myapp.war then creating an application version with the s3 bucket as `mybucket` and `test/myapp.war` is the way to do it. Not sure why you are getting the VPC related error. When and where do you see that error? When you create an application version or when you create an environment? Does the API call throw the error message immediately do you see that in the events later?

Comment: thanks, but the path of war that i want to deploy is `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/ROOT.war`, but when i'm entering this as S3-URL, it is not accepting it, i also tried with `https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/ROOT.war` and `https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/ROOT.war` but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is fine ... in the s3 url above S3Bucket is "mybucket", and object key is "ROOT.war". If you are launching an elastic beanstalk environment in us-west-2, then make sure that 'mybucket' is also created in region 'us-west-2'.

Comment: thnx, i was able to deploy it, but last thing, how can i deploy next version of ROOT.war? the above step is done for the first time, how can I deploy next version?

Comment: Create a new application version `v2` with the s3 bucket and s3 object key. Then run call UpdateEnvironment API with version label v2. This will update your environment to the latest version of your file. You can use DescribeEnvironment and DescribeEvents API to see the status of the update. Read more here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateEnvironment.html

Comment: You can also use alternative tools like web console, CLIs depending on what you find convenient.

Comment: Thanks, i solved it by creating the environment from web-console using s3 bucket. Whenever i want to deploy a new build i upload ROOT.war in bucket from my dev server and then in app server i simply redeploy the ROOT.war, which is now replaced by the new build.