# Where is / What is the s3key referred to in beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I hate asking this but I have looked throughout this site and Google and can't find the answer.

Beanstalk refers to this URL:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3Bucket/s3Key

is the s3 key the same that is available via each users credentials page? Eg Access Key ID and Secret Access Key? If so which one is it? Its not very clear and I can't seem to find anything. I do see people referring to a .war file but not sure where that file is?

[Deploy war from S3 to AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683649/deploy-war-from-s3-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

**EDIT**

This is the exact error:

Could not launch environment: Unable to download from S3 location (Bucket: mybucketname Key: **ACCESS KEY ID?**). Reason: Not Found

Answer (score 1):

The s3Key here is synonymous with the path. S3 doesnt really have paths or folders and the / is just another character in the "key". So thats the S3 URL were you upload the .war to.

Comment: I assume in that case that it would be https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucketname but I am getting an error saying the key must be provided?

Comment: Maybe mention that in the question. A .war is a java app. In case of Rails you make a .zip that also goes to S3. Do you use the cli to deploy?

Comment: If you use the EB CLI it creates the bucket for you and uploads the .zip to to it, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html#ruby-rails-tutorial-deploy

Comment: `s3.amazonaws.com/mybucketname` is a bucket name, not an object key. The object key would be everything after that part.